# API page number parameter looping

Tags: bash, rest, shell, api, command-line

I am currently trying to work with the API documentation for an app. In order to call it, I'm using the code:

```
curl -X GET \
  'https://api.program.com/v1/notes?page=1&pageSize=1000&sort=desc' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer xxx123xxx456xxx789xxx0001' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache'
```

The token is changed here for obvious reasons. But what I'm really trying to setup involves the `page=1` parameter. My question is two-fold:

1. How can I write a command that will capture all pages within the
   current structure of the command? So basically, after `page=1` it
   will then run `page=2`, `page=3`, etc...
2. How can I do this in a way that also identifies when there are no more pages left, and thus, knows when to end running?

My current setup looks like this, but it's giving me what I need:

```
for ((i=1;i<=5;i++)); do
  curl -X GET \
  'https://api.program.com/v1/notes?page=1&pageSize=1000&sort=desc' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer xxx123xxx456xxx789xxx0001' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache'
done
```

The result when there is no more records left looks like this:

```
{
    "meta": {
        "pageSize": 1000,
        "page": 65
    },
    "links": {
        "self": "/v1/conversations?page=65&pageSize=1000&sort=desc",
        "first": "/v1/conversations?page=1&pageSize=1000&sort=desc",
        "prev": "/v1/conversations?page=64&pageSize=1000&sort=desc",
        "next": null
    },
    "data": []
}
```

Comment: Use a loop until you get whatever the API uses to signal that there aren't any more records?

Comment: Is this a suggestion or are you asking me a question?

Comment: It is a suggestion.

Comment: Right, so how would one do that? How does it identify there are no more records?

Comment: We don't know and we cannot know. It's you the one that have access to the API documentation to check how this API signals the end of the records.

Comment: Well -- what does that particular website send you when you ask for a non-existent document -- what does it return?  There is probably an indication of failure, so check its return (when you run that `curl` command in a Perl script you can capture its return, probably having 404 in there).   Or, what does your `curl` command get you -- a file? Then check after each run whether the file is there.

Comment: Have a close read of the API documentation: the returned payload should indicate if there are more results.

Comment: Got it! I just edited what it appears to look like when it goes to a page number that doesn't appear to have records @Poshi

Comment: Great :).  So do you now know what to do with it?  If not: when you say "_The result when..._", do you mean that you get back that JSON (as a string in the output)? Also, is that `65` the last page that was loaded (and you asked perhaps for 66 to get this?)

Comment: @zdim - sorry for not being more clear. So I was more just playing around trying to figure out what's the first `page=i` that would result in no data and that is what the page looks like when it doesn't have data (which I imagine is represented in `"data": []` so I think it's that part in which determines if there is data or not. I'd imagine when I write the final code, it will be done with something like `.date[]` or whatever the JQ formatting code would be

Comment: OK, then you're good :).  The empty `data` is probably the sign that there is no page -- but the `links` section in JSON seems to spell it out.  (You may well be getting this back on every run, in which case can parse it to find out whether there is `next` link)